# Construct a HashMap without overriding the key by summing the values to an existing key from an array

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8

I'm trying to construct a HashMap from below array

```
product: [
 {
  id: 12345
  qty: 5
 },
 {
  id: 12345
  qty: 6
 },
 {
  id: 98765
  qty: 10
 }
]
```

**code:**

```
HashMap<Long, Integer> productMap = new HashMap<>();
int totalQty = 0;

for (Product product : products) {
 Long id = product.getId();
 if (productMap.containsKey(id)) {
  productMap.put(id, totalQty + productMap.get(id).intValue());
 } else {
  productMap.put(id, totalQty);
 }
}
```

from the above method I'm checking the key from the map, if yes add the qty to the totalQty by overriding the existing key, any best approach to not override the while summing the values ??

Comment: .intValue() is redundant . Java will do autoboxing and unboxing. You could use java 8 constructs and make concise

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do like this:

```
products.stream().collect(toMap(Product::getId,Product::getQty,Intger::sum));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, isn't it .collect(Collectors.toMap) ??

Comment: @Ramana Yes. I assume @Hadi J used a static import for `java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap`.